# Get image width and height working 50% of the time in vue js

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, vuejs3, onload

I have this structure in a view file, in Vue js (EDITED):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{quiz.name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="quizForm">
        <div class="quizQuestContainer">
            <div class="quizQuestions" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions"
            :key = index >
            <div v-if="index === questionIndex">
                <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li v-for="(response, index) in question.responses"
                        :key = index
                    >
                    <label>
                       
                        <input type="radio" 
                            :value="[response.res_value === question.solution]"
                            :name="index" 
                        > {{response.res_text}}
                    </label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <button v-if="questionIndex > 0" v-on:click="prev">
                    prev
                </button>
                <button v-on:click="next">
                    next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
            <h2> Quiz finished</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quizImage">
            <div class="ImageArea">
                <img :src="imageCrop(quiz.iiif)">
                <br/>    
            </div>
</template>
<script>
    import sourceData from '@/data.json'

    export default {
      props:{
        id: {type: String, required: true}
      },
      data(){
        return {
            questionIndex: 0,

        }
      },

      computed:{
        quiz(){
            return sourceData.quizzes.find(quiz =>quiz.id === parseInt(this.id))
            },
        },
       methods: {
         // Go to next question
       next: function() {
         this.questionIndex++;
       },
       // Go to previous question
       prev: function() {
           this.questionIndex--;
       },

       imageCrop: function(iiif) { 
          let image = new Image();
          image.src = iiif; 
          let width =  image.width; 
          let height = image.height;
          return image.src + " this is width " + width + " and this is height " + height
       }
</script>
```

Sometimes I get the right height and width, but sometimes I get 0 and 0. Are there some caching problems? Is methods the right way to do this? I am new to Vue, so I don't understand very well how it works.

EDIT: If I use

```
 image.onload = () => {
       let height = image.height;
       let width = image.width;
       return image.src + " this is width " + width + " and this is height " + height
 }
```

Nothing appear on the page. I tried to put an error handling like that:

```
nameError: function(){
        try {
            const error = new Error();
            return error.message;
        } catch (ex) {
            return ex.message;
        }
```

and it generates an event with this in the DOM:

> const invoker = (e) => {
> // async edge case #6566: inner click event triggers patch, event handler
> // attached to outer element during patch, and triggered again. This
> // happens because browsers fire microtask ticks between event propagation.
> // the solution is simple: we save the timestamp when a handler is attached,
> // and the handler would only fire if the event passed to it was fired
> // AFTER it was attached.
> const timeStamp = e.timeStamp || _getNow();
> if (skipTimestampCheck || timeStamp >= invoker.attached - 1) {
> callWithAsyncErrorHandling(patchStopImmediatePropagation(e,
> invoker.value), instance, 5 /* NATIVE_EVENT_HANDLER */, [e]);
> }

The data JSON is like that:

```
{
    "quizzes": [
      {
        "name": "Quiz A",
        "slug": "quiz-1",
        "image": "D000533S_AlbiniW_ST40.jpg",
        "iiif": "https://gallica.bnf.fr/iiif/ark:/12148/btv1b9042253v/f1/full/,550/0/native.jpg", 
        "id": 1,
        "description":
          "First quiz",
        "questions": [
            {
              "text": "Question 1",
              "responses": [
                {"res_text": "Wrong",
                  "res_value": "a"
                }, 
                {"res_text": "Right",
                  "res_value": "b"
                }
              ],
              "solution": "a"
            }, 
            {
              "text": "Question 2",
              "responses": [
                {"res_text": "Right",
                  "res_value": "a"
                }, 
                {"res_text": "Wrong",
                  "res_value": "b"
                }
              ],
              "solution": "b"
          }
        ]
      },
```

etc.

Comment: I believe you need your image to load before measuring its dimensions (`image.onload = function() {  get dimensions here  }`)

Comment: I thought it was done already with `new Image()`. I'll try

Comment: new Image() jut creates an Image Object. Setting the src then tells the browser to load that image, but this is an asynchronous process. Therefore when you try to get the width and height of the image, most of the time you won't get the result you expect. I assume it works sometimes, because the browser has already downloaded and cached the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by @theshark, creating an image to retrieve its dimensions is an asynchronous process. AFAIK, you won't be able to use the result of such method in the rendering.

It's unclear what is it you're trying to achieve, but the easiest way would be to store the dimensions in your component's data once your `imageCrop` method got them. This method won't have to be called in the template, but rather in a `created` hook.

You can directly bind you component's data in your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>{{quiz.name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="myImageData">
       {{ src }} this is width {{ width }} and this is height {{ height }}
    </div>
    <div class="quizImage">
        <div class="ImageArea">
          <img :src="src">
          <br/>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <button @click="prev">⬅️</button>
    <button @click="next">➡️</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import sourceData from '@/data.json'
export default {
 props:{
    id: {type: String, required: true}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      src: "",
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      questionIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  computed:{
    quiz(){
      return sourceData.quizzes.find(quiz => quiz.id === this.questionIndex);
    },
  },
  updated() {
    this.imageCrop();
  },
  created() {
    this.questionIndex = parseInt(this.id);
    this.imageCrop();
  },
  methods: {
   next: function() {
     this.questionIndex++;
   },
   prev: function() {
     this.questionIndex--;
   },
   imageCrop: function() {
      const iiif = this.quiz.iiif;
      let image = new Image();
      image.onload = (event) => {
        this.width = event.target.width;
        this.height = event.target.height;
        this.src = event.target.src;
      }
      image.src = iiif; 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

(after seeing the complete code I'd advise splitting the logic into smaller components)

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is that in the template I am calling a specific data from a json where the url is stored. This is actually a computed function. So I need to pass the computed in the template, I think.

`computed:{
        quiz(){
            return sourceData.quizzes.find(quiz =>quiz.id === parseInt(this.id))
            },
        },`

And in the template i call `{{ imageCrop(quiz.iiif) }}`

Comment: You should post a complete code sample with components hierarchy in order to get relevant help

Comment: You are right, I edited with the complete code

Comment: This code doesn't look complete to me; what link is there between this.id & this.questionIndex? What does your data structure (data.json) looks like? The template has more than one root element, etc.
I updated my answer to match your code though.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the incompleteness

Comment: Yes, my idea is to split into smaller components, but I wanted to have a sketch of it working first. Thank you